# Using multiprocess or multithreading for numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a function that takes a NumPy array as an args. I need to use this function N times to get N different outputs.

```
x1 = np.random.rand(10**6)
x2 = np.random.rand(10**6)
.
.
xn = np.random.rand(10**6)


 def s_1d_nb1(x):
    a= np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range (len(x)):
        a[i] = (np.mean((x[i :] - x[: len(x)-i])**2))
    return a
new_x1 = s_1d_nb1(x1)
new_x2 = s_1d_nb1(x2)
.
.
new_xn = s_1d_nb1(xn)
```

Is there any way to run `new_x1`, `new_x2`, .. `new_xn` using multiprocessing?

Comment: before attempting to use multiple threads or processes, you can try to determine if you can rewrite your algorithm using native numpy operations.

Comment: @jakub  a good suggestion.. I will rewrite and update the answer.